# how to add a dns ro resolve wireguard endpoint when using wg setconfg instead of wg-quick

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, wireguard

Following wireguard docs for [ordinary-containerization](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#ordinary-containerization) it works with something similar to this configuration file:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
#
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=

[Peer]
PublicKey = BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = 11.111.111.111:51820
# Problem, using the following Endpoint won't work
# and the DNS entry is not allowed with wg setconf
# Endpoint = my.vpn.location.com:51820
```

The problem is that endpoint needs to be an ip, as soon as it's a domain wireguard is not able to resolve it during `link set gw0 up`.

Since in ordinary containerization `wg setconf` is used no DNS and Address are allowed in the Interface section.

The following would work with `wg-quick` though

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
#
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
Address = 10.14.0.2/16
DNS = 123.456.789.01

[Peer]
PublicKey = BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = my.vpn.location.com:51820
```

`wg-quick` is able to resolve `my.vpn.location.com` but how do one tells `wg setconfg` how to resolve `my.vpn.location.com` instead of having to hard code the ip for the Endpoint?

NOTE:
This are the commands I use to set it up with `wg setconf` where endpoint with ip works but not with a domain.

```
# ip netns add container
# ip link add wg0 type wireguard
# ip link set wg0 netns container
# ip -n container addr add 10.14.0.2/16 dev wg0
# ip netns exec container wg setconf wg0 /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
# ip -n container link set wg0 up
# ip -n container route add default dev wg0
```

As suggested this question was brought here from [networkengineering.stackexchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85330/how-to-add-a-dns-ro-resolve-wireguard-endpoint-when-using-wg-setconfg-instead-of)

Comment: `wg setconf` uses `getaddrinfo()` which does use DNS resolution (probably depending in nsswitch.conf etc). If your WG interface is isolated in a namespace not able to do DNS resolution, or perhaps the DNS queries going through the tunnel when it shouldn't etc, then you might have an other problem. tested `wg setconf` here: does resolve DNS (visible with `strace` showing `wg` emitting UDP to DNS server on port 53). Your problem doesn't appear to be directly a `wg` command problem. Also `wg(8)` tells "Endpoint  — an endpoint IP **or hostname**"

Comment: I think my issue is what you said *WG interface is isolated in a namespace not able to do DNS resolution*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wg(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/wg.8.html#CONFIGURATION_FILE_FORMAT) documents it does accept hostnames, meaning it will resolve them, including using DNS (which is standard in a default setup):

> - Endpoint — an endpoint IP **or hostname**, followed by a colon, and then a port number. [...]

indeed [the code](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/tree/src/config.c?h=v1.0.20210914#n242) uses [`getaddrinfo(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html):

> ```
>   ret = getaddrinfo(begin, end, &hints, &resolved);
> ```

The issue is because the command (`wg` but the same would happen with `wg-quick`) is run in an environment where there is no network available: a brand new container with no interface providing connectivity yet, so a resolution attempt relying on DNS can only fail at this step.

---

Since `wg` (contrary to `wg-quick`) won't touch addresses or routing but only WireGuard properties, just change order of operations: configure the interface's WireGuard properties on the host namespace, where DNS resolution works, only then move it to the target namespace, and finally complete its configuration there. This becomes:

```shell
# ip netns add container
# ip link add wg0 type wireguard
# wg setconf wg0 /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf          # altered, was #5
# ip link set wg0 netns container                 # was #3
# ip -n container addr add 10.14.0.2/16 dev wg0   # was #4
# ip -n container link set wg0 up
# ip -n container route add default dev wg0
```

This will run `wg` on the host instead of the container, but the end result will be the same: the container will have the single `wg0` interface, and this interface will have a listen port only on the host.

Comment: That makes sense and works, thanks.

Comment: @Cesc added the actual reason as discussed in previous comments.